# select not working moving to angular controller as

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I have a procedure wrote using typescript that I'm upgrading to angular 1.3 and I'm converting the controllers to controllers as model, and I have an issue.
I have a select defined this way:

```
<select id="soluzione" name="soluzione"
        class="required"
        ng-options="soluzione.id as soluzione.denominazione for soluzione in soluzioni"
        ng-model="soluzioneCorrente"
        ng-change="filtroSoluzione()">
```

where **soluzioni** is an array loaded using a ajax call in the costruction of the controller. Using the controller with scope the list is populated correctly.
after the update I changed the definition to

```
<select id="soluzione" name="soluzione"
        class="required"
        ng-options="soluzione.id as soluzione.denominazione for soluzione in vm.soluzioni"
        ng-model="vm.soluzioneCorrente"
        ng-change="vm.filtroSoluzione()"></select>
```

but the select is not loaded anymore.
I'm missing something? Checking with batarang looks like the scope is exposed correctly and other event handlers are called in the correct way, so I think I converted the controller.

luca

Comment: Can you post more code of what the controller looks like or create a jsFiddle? From first glance, I don't think you need the "vm."

Comment: Could you please show the data soluzione. The use of VM is not necessary. Please show your controller, then we can see the state of your $scope. If you could make a jsFiddle example, it would be really helpful

Comment: Hi, I'm facing the same issue. Where you able to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have `ng-controller="SomeController as vm"` inside your HTML